# Is that possible to use constant memory address value for different time?

Tags: c++, c, operating-system

1. sometimes p=3,which memory &p=somehexadecimal and this values  changing frequently .
2. why its memory value changing?
3. Is that possible to maintain **constant memory value for p**?

Comment: Why do you need that? What do you mean by "it's changing"?

Comment: Ohh, OP is asking whether a variable can be made to always be stored at the same address.

Comment: You don't get to control where variables are stored. You might be able to consult your linker documentation to see if your platform allows you to prescribe addresses of certain global objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use a variable in static memory, it will be located at the same address through the run of the program.

A global is an example, a `static` class member, namespace `static` or function-scope `static`s are others.

Answer (score 0):

c & c++ users runtime memory allocation so it will allocate from available memory.
I don't think there is any way to allocate static memory address to any variable.

Comment: Funnily, you used the word `static` :-)

Comment: Even `static` variables don't have a static address in physical memory *during execution* (due to paging), though they do have a static virtual memory address; and if Address Space Layout Randomization (ASLR) is enabled, they won't even have one in virtual memory between two executions.

Comment: i didnt mention static variable i said we cant allocate static memory address to any variable.